# How to hide URL Bar in Ionic 5 Capacitor using Browser Plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Checking the new Ionic Capacitor Docs, there seems NO OPTION to hide the url bar of the Browser Plugin (Previously InAppBrowser) at the moment. Need help please.

Comment: I've been playing with this today, I can only hide the url bar with the original https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/in-app-browser unfortunatelly. Capacitor plugin doesnt let you do this.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1803) on a GitHub Issue thread, this is not going to be possible due to the fact that both the IAB and Browser plugins use `SFSafariViewController`, which doesn't allow you to hide the native controls.

That said, this has been driving me crazy for a while now, as I can't hide the URL bar in either OS even when using the original IAB.

Comment: Oh, thats a pity.

Comment: Time for a new plugin wrapping WKWebView then.

Answer (score -3):

I use iframe to solve the problem

```
<iframe src='https://stackoverflow.com/' />
```

ps: url use https

Comment: Can you explain more how it solves the problem.